# Как пользоваться AsymmetricGridView?

Tags: android, adapter, gridview

Как отобразить три изображения в сообщении диалога с помощью [эту библиотеки](http://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1186)?
Подключил, как написано в описании. 
 
Объясните (с примером кода), что должно быть в качестве адаптера **adapter = new ListAdapter(this, listView, items);**? Мне постоянно пустоту выводит, вместо ожидаемого результата.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (AsymmetricGridView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        // Choose your own preferred column width
        listView.setRequestedColumnWidth(Utils.dpToPx(this, 120));
        final List<AsymmetricItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

        // initialize your items array
        adapter = new ListAdapter(this, listView, items);
        AsymmetricGridViewAdapter asymmetricAdapter =
            new AsymmetricGridViewAdapter<>(this, listView, adapter);
        listView.setAdapter(asymmetricAdapter);
    }
```

Или подскажет другую библиотеку, с помощью которой можно проще выполнить аналогичные действия?

Answer (score 1):

В проекте есть [пример использования](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/felipecsl/asymmetricgridview/app) этой библиотеки, который можно изучить и сделать так же и [несколько видов адаптеров](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/felipecsl/asymmetricgridview/app/widget), которые можно "скормить" этой библиотеке.

Вы можете использовать готовый или на их основе  сделать свой.

Comment: Спасибо, я думал это сама либа. Я еще новичок, и с библиотеками редко работал, в основном пытался обходиться стандартными средствами.

Comment: @5mi13 Код самой библиотеки [вот](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView/tree/master/library)